# How is .upsertMany() implemented in Prisma ORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

Prisma ORM has an implementation of the [update or create `upsert()`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-or-create-records) method and a group of
[bulk requests](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/query-optimization-performance#using-bulk-queries),
but there is no such thing as `.upsertMany()`, i.e. bulk "create or update existing records".

What is the best way to implement such a method using [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prisma doesn't natively support `upsertMany`.

There is a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4134) to provide the `upsertMany` method.

As of now the best approach would be to loop over the data and invoke `upsert` in the loop along with using `$transaction`.

Example:

```js
const collection = await prisma.$transaction(
    userData.map(cur =>
      prisma.cur.upsert({
        where: { id: cur.id },
        update: {},
        create: { id: cur.id },
      })
    )
  )
```

Here's a reference to [$transaction](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api) API which should be helpful.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some techniological barrier for why there isn't a better way of doing this? But if I want to upsert 10 million records of demo data, using their own seeding system, I'd have to actually fire 10 million separate queries against the db?

Answer (score 0):

I do wonder if instead of using the `$transaction` API and looping over the data, it would be more performant to check against the DB if each record should be inserted or updated and then use a `createMany` along with `updateMany`.

Comment: If you do this, make sure you have a plan for stale reads for concurrent connections. I believe this can lead to a situation where (1) You do your read, (2) Another user issues a create, (3) You issue your create and get an error from Prisma. Won't happen if you're just working with test data, but at high scale and/or high data overlap will probably give you issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use upsert to update multiple objects like the following:
In the following example, I am updating a user's profile and upserting multiple addresses by using the map function.

```
await this.prisma.user.update({
                where: {
                    id: user.id
                },
                data:{
                    fullName: saveUserProfileDto?.fullName,
                    email: saveUserProfileDto?.email,
                    
                    userAddresses: {
                        upsert: saveUserProfileDto?.addresses?.map(address => ({
                            where: {
                                uuid: address.uuid || ""
                            },
                            create: {
                                uuid: uuidv4(),
                                country: address.country,
                                cityTown: address.cityTown,
                                streetAddress: address.streetAddress,
                                apartmentSuit: address.apartmentSuit,
                            },
                            update: {
                                country: address.country,
                                cityTown: address.cityTown,
                                streetAddress: address.streetAddress,
                                apartmentSuit: address.apartmentSuit,
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                }
            });
```

**So you don't need to delete anything before upserting.**